# Convert html to plain text Python

Tags: python, html, plaintext

Good morning, I am looking for a way to convert the html code to plain text, I leave an example

HTML

```
<div class="card-headline"><h3 class="card-title">
```

Texto Plano

```
&lt;div class=&quot;card-headline&quot;&gt;&lt;h3 class=&quot;card-title&quot;&gt;
```

Comment: If you're going to be generating much HTML I'd recommend using a library to do so.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BeautifulSoup is a scraping library, so it's probably not the best choice for doing HTML rendering. If it's not essential to use BeautifulSoup, you should take a look at html2text. For example:

- import html2text
- html = open("foobar.html").read()
- print html2text.html2text(html)

This outputs:

Some text more text even more text

- list item
- yet another list item

Some other text

- list item
- yet another list item